# How to reset Star Rating on a single Item in SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Just like the question says.

we already tried disabling and re-enabling the rating system but this doesn't seems to provoke any changes

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code on my add-in and it works.

```
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostCtx = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostUrl);

var targetList = hostCtx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList1');

var targeListItem = targetList.getItemById(1);

targeListItem.set_item('RatedBy', null);
targeListItem.set_item('RatingCount', null);
targeListItem.set_item('Ratings', null);
targeListItem.set_item('AverageRating', null);

targeListItem.update();

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
function (s, a) // Success
{
    alert("ok");
},
function (s, e) // Error
{
    alert(e.get_message());
});

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```